# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{π^n+n}{3^n+n!} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine whether the series

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{π^n+n}{3^n+n!} $

is convergent or divergent.

Is a positive series and I can see that for $x\to \infty  $

$\frac{π^n}{n!}$

and I don't know how to use the comparison test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It converges.
$$
0\le \frac{\pi^n + n}{3^n+n!}\le  \frac{2\pi ^n}{n!}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{2\pi^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{2\pi^n}{n!}}=0,
$$
so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2\pi^n}{n!}$ converges by ratio test. Therefore, given series converges by the comparison test.

Comment: you even can compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\frac{\pi^n}{n!} = 2 (e^{\pi}-1)$

Comment: @MJ73550 Thanks for giving exact value of that. It is from $e^x =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$, right?

Comment: @choco_addicted Yep it is.

Comment: @choco_addicted Why the numeratior is $2\pi^n$ ? thanks

Comment: I replaced $n$ with $\pi^n$, because $n < \pi^n$ is true for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.